# Most of my assets suddenly return 404 after a push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have deployed this app (rails 3.2.11) a million times, I haven't messed with any settings, but now I'm greeted with this:

[image]

Why did this happen out of the blue? My conents of application.rb include `config.assets.enabled = true` - never had any issues.

**In fact running it locally on port 3000 seems to not have any issues whatsoever.**

After deploying to heroku this morning, it seems that it loads nothing that's inside /assets/

Interestingly, after copying the files over to try and just make a new app, `git commit` results in all the stuff you'd expect as well as a LONG list of these which I think might be related:

[image]

Edit: Interestingly enough SOME of the assets have loaded, like the logo and the background, but the rest as you can see return 404.

Comment: pretty you need to set config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false in production and application.rb files, though just in the application.rb file normally suffices

Comment: Richlewis - adding that to production did not help

Comment: what about just adding it to the  application.rb file?

Comment: I'm about to find out but running rake assets:precompile has been taking an awfully long time for some reason

Comment: aaaand it didn't work.

Comment: During the push to heroku, are there any errors during the asset precompilation phase?

Comment: Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (83.33s)
-----> Rails plugin injection - nothing too interesting. However see my updated question.

Comment: Did you update Rails recently? Rails 4 specifically could have an impact here, but I can't suggest much without knowing the rails version.

Comment: That it runs fine locally is almost inconsequential, unless you're running it locally in production mode. Can you run this `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` successfully?

Comment: ctshryock, I ran the command, there was no output. I take that means it's a success? Now what? It's 3.2.11, by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem today with rails 4 on heroku. The article provided by @Jeff is a little bit old but, [the gem repository](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#static-assets) has a good readme.
Summarizing, you will need to add two gems to your Gemfile:

1. `gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'` (it will solve the static assets problem) and
2. `gem 'rails_stdout_logging'` (which the previous one depends on).

Comment: Great update. I'll change the correct answer as I agree the current ones are a bit old.

Comment: They've combined both of those gems in the 12 factor gem: https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor (which is now required if you're running Rails 4+ on Heroku). Adding this gem solved my problem.

Comment: Really? My app is still there and I'm not using this gem. I'll check that. Thanks!

Comment: I have these two in my Gemfile and I'm still having an issue accessing my assets. My Gemfile has `gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'`, `gem 'rails_stdout_logging'`, and `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`. What am I missing? :/  (I've `bundle install`'ed and pushed to Heroku.)

Comment: Adding `gem rails_12factor` solved same issue we were facing. thanks @ryanjones

Comment: This didn't help for me. I'm using haml for view, and javascript_include_tag "application" is refering "app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee". It works in development environment, but with production. above 3 gems didn't help my problem in heroku with production environment.

Answer (score 16):

put line in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

it worked as it will compile the assets on runtime, just like in development environment, but its makes application slow, the best way is to either compile the assets locally in production environment with rake task(RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile) and commit your generated assets in public/assets and then do deployment. or, heroku run rake assets:precompile

Comment: That was easy. Can you explain a little bit why that worked, why that wasn't necessary before?

Comment: it worked as it will compile the assets on runtime, just like in development environment, but its makes application slow, the best way is to either compile the assets locally in production environment with rake task(RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile) and commit your generated assets in public/assets and then do deployment.

or,  heroku run rake assets:precompile

Comment: This is not really a good answer.  Manually compiling assets is not equivalent to serving precompiled assets.

Comment: @te_chris, may be is not the good idea but if written more in my comments if you can read, first precompile the assets locally and then commit them.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Heroku released a gem to handle the assets without needing to turn off compilation or to manually compile.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#static-assets

Just add this to your Gemfile and redeploy.

```
gem 'rails_serve_static_assets', group: [:production]
```

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 4, use:

`config.serve_static_assets = true`

The default was false. We needed this after removing the rails_12factor gem.

Comment: I've done this -- too -- for all three environments 

Answer (score 2):

Rails recommended that this setting `config.serve_static_assets` by default should be disabled i.e. set to false. Here is the default configuration in `config/environments/production.rb` generated in rails app

#### Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)

`config.serve_static_assets = false`

So if you are setting it to true in your local app then that's still fine. But if you are deploying your app on Apache or ngix or anything other than heroku then its not advisable to make `config.serve_static_assets=true` in your production.rb config file. Here is the documentation from Rails guides.

> config.serve_static_files configures Rails itself to serve static
>   files. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned
>   off as the server software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the
>   application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default
>   setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or
>   testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won't
>   be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly
>   under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.

URL - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 0):

To make the assets to load with the corresponding fingerprint of each file verify the configuration `config/environments/production.rb` has the instruction:

`ruby
  # Load assets with fingerprint behavior
  config.assets.digest = true`