# Rails 4: run application in production mode after assets precompile gives assets not found issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, production-environment, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using rails 4.1.8

In production.rb file i have following:

```
  config.eager_load = false
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = false
  config.assets.debug = true
```

Now after running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` it precompiles all the assets and store them public/assets folder with file name `application-ca4ad5e0582927b0a78c2b6feef3309b.js`

after running application in production environment on my local, it throws error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.js"):
```

I tried with changing values of config.serve_static_assets and others.. but still facing same issue.

The precompiled files are saved with digest values in their name, for ex: `application-ca4ad5e0582927b0a78c2b6feef3309b.js` but accessed as `application.js`, this is causing main issue.

Any suggestions here?? Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer this discussion here - [Most of my assets suddenly return 404 after a push to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669991/most-of-my-assets-suddenly-return-404-after-a-push-to-heroku)
This is the exact issue we were facing.

Adding 12 factor gem: [github.com/heroku/rails_12factor](http://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) fixes this issue. (This gem is now required if you're running Rails 4+ on Heroku). 
I tried adding gem 'rails_12factor' in the same repo you were working and this loads all assets just fine.

Basically this `rails_12factor` gem is a combination of 2 gems viz. `rails_serve_static_assets` and `rails_stdout_logging`. Gem `rails_serve_static_assets` just sets this  configuration to true. This is generally in your config/environments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

So in general, if we are developing a `Rails4` app and we deploy on our own servers (say a dedicated server and not heroku) then setting this flag `config.serve_static_assets` to true  is sufficient and we don't need to add rails_12 factor or any other gems. Here is the code of `rails_serve_static_assets` gem which is used by `rails_12factor` gem.

```
module RailsServeStaticAssets
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.before_initialize do
      if Rails.version >= "4.2.0"
        ::Rails.configuration.serve_static_files = true
      else
        ::Rails.configuration.serve_static_assets = true
      end
      ::Rails.configuration.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @Swati, I was checking how gem `rails_12factor` solved this issue. And after checking code and their documentation ... all it does is combine gems `rails_serve_static_assets` and `rails_stdout_logging`. Gem `rails_serve_static_assets` enables Rails server to deliver assets directly, instead of returning a 404. This gem achieves this behavior in the app by simply setting a single configuration option, config.serve_static_assets = true. By using the rails_serve_static_assets gem, you do not need to set this configuration manually.  :-)

Comment: And @Swati, the fix that we need was this `config.serve_static_assets = true` if we don't want to use all these Gems. This configuration needed to be enabled due to Rails4 changes. Gem `rails_serve_static_assets` enables that flag for us if we use it. Otherwise its just a configuration issue due to Rails4 changes.

Answer (score 3):

The asset pipeline in Rails 4 does not compile assets without a digest. The default is to only compile digested assets. This option does nothing:

```
config.assets.digest = false  # Will not compile undigested assets
```

You need to use a rails helper to generate the digested path to `application.js`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

If that's not an option, you can use one of the various strategies to generate non-digested assets:

- [non stupid digest assets gem](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets)
- [custom rake task](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-20535134)
- [rack middleware to serve non-digested assets](https://github.com/zarqman/smart_assets)
- [sprockets redirects](https://github.com/sikachu/sprockets-redirect)

[This github issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49) on the sprocket-rails project has a lot of discussion and workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Eklund, indeed wonderful discussion on the link you shared here - [link](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49) and this led to knowledge about why Rails took that decision on asset hash. Unfortunately we tried all the 4 solutions you mentioned above and none of them helped. Finally adding `gem 'rails_12factor'` made it work for us. Seems we had different issue with asset 404 error. And we didn't want to do this `config.assets.compile =true` on local while we were testing for `production` mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable fallback to asset pipeline, in production.rb:

```
config.assets.compile =true
```

This means that you are doing compilation on the fly(locally for you to test), but when you deploy to production remove this line or set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

@Swati, first clean the assert pipeline by-

**rake asset:clean** and then run

RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Comment: As Swati mentioned above as per that it is clear she is doing these steps. Does not look like problem is with precompile.

Comment: Yeah issue is not with `precompile` as assets are getting generated properly with correct digest. Thus, the above clean command didn't help much. This issue had more to do with sprockets and how Rails 4 manages asset digest while compiling. BTW you have a typo in the above command, it should be `rake assets:clean`  :)