# 404 error for CSS file installed with Yarn on Heroku - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I installed tooltip - `jQuery` library. One CSS and one JS file.
I added them to `application.scss` and `application.js`:

```
@import 'tooltipster.css';
```

and

```
//= require tooltipster
```

In `localhost`, I don't have this problem and all works fine.

When I upload to `Heroku` (`git push heroku master`) and access the site, I see in the browser console with red color that `tooltipster.css` can't be loaded:

```
GET https://mysite.herokuapp.com/assets/tooltipster.css
```

, but in `localhost` everything works.

The `rails_12factor` in production, doesn't fix my problem.

This line in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

fix the problem, but I don't want to use it in production.

Comment: seems like your app still thinks it is in development mode when loading the assets. it should be compiling them into one minified file and loading just that file with some md5 hash in the filename. I have a hunch your whole app is not setting the "production" environment which should be handling that all for you. This link might help point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671615/1231563

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most of my assets suddenly return 404 after a push to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669991/most-of-my-assets-suddenly-return-404-after-a-push-to-heroku)

Comment: Not duplicate, with 12_factor gem 1 image is with 404 error in Heroku. With `config.assets.compile = true`, everything works fine, but I don't want to use it.